# Hover event not working with :not selector

Tags: jquery

I tried to make a hover event fire for all elements in my script with 2 exceptions. I thought this would be possible by using the :not selector. But for some reason it doesn't work.

```
$('*:not(#li1):not(.dropdown)').hover(function(){


scroll_1.hide();


});
```

I also tried the

```
if(Element.is(':hover')){}  // This is not my exact code, it is only an example
```

Can anyone please explain why you can't do something like this and what would be the appropriate way to do it, if there is any at all.

Comment: Yeah just noticed it as well, but thanks for the heads up anyways!

Comment: Was that the issue?  Your selector is missing a closing `'`

Comment: After you fixed those syntax errors, are you still seeing it not work?

Comment: No, it was merely a typo. This code still doesn't work accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `hover` event to `body` and use `event.stopPropagation()` on elements where you don't want it to fired.

```
$('body').on('hover', function(event){
 //Your hover function
});

$('#li1').on('hover', function(event){
 event.stopPropagation();
});

$('.dropdown').on('hover', function(event){
 event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much! This must get the job done indeed.

Comment: Happy to help. Accept it as answer so that others can also benefit from it.